# Anyone have luck doing bare metal development for the Pi 2 using the tools from Xcode?

Tags: bare-metal

I have my eyes in doing bare metal development on the Pi 2. However I have nowhere to install a Linux to as my Mac's hard drive (retrofitted 480GB SSD) is almost full. So anyone have luck in writing bare metal code using the set of tools that came with Xcode?

Xcode shipped with an Apple-patched version of LLVM/clang that (since iPhones used them) supports emitting ARMv7 and ARMv6 code. Now how should I make the rest of the toolchain work?

Comment: Have you considered online services like AWS? Some of the online dev environment services like cloud nine may also work - most of them offer some terminal access to a linux box.

Comment: Apple's stock clang emits ELF but cannot call the ELF linker properly. However it seem to me that the kernel image can be in any binary format so Mach-O may be used. I am not putting my code to any cloud services.